# Отсутствует перевод всплывающего сообщения в очереди голосов за переоткрытие

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, переоткрытие-вопросов

Всплывающее сообщение, показываемое, если не выбрать причину, почему вопрос следует оставить закрытым, и нажать "Оставить закрытым" в [очереди голосов за переоткрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/) написано на английском:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(текст - `You must select a reason before submitting.`)

PS: А вообще-то странно: например, при голосовании за закрытие кнопка "Голосовать за закрытие" неактивна пока не выберешь причину - почему бы так не сделать и здесь?

Comment: Тут ещё одна [старая проблемка](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371747/339911) проглядывает на картинке.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так вот откуда взялся этот "Младший редактор"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оригинал:

> You must select a reason before submitting.

Предложил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17108):

> Вы должны выбрать причину перед отправкой.

Comment: Перевод утвердил. Текущая сборка rev 2023.11.15.1019

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, быстро )

Comment: Только вот что-то оно не подхватилось. Добавил ещё [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18747) для окна следующего уровня. Понаблюдаем далее. Текущая сборка 2023.11.20.1249

Comment: Завёл багу на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394864/339911). Текущая сборка 2023.11.21.1314

Comment: Похоже, там [глобально всё отсохло](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395096/339911) с переводами.